# extract 3D system from a 2D picture

Tags: opencv, 3d

I'm working on a project, I want to find some specific line from a picture and extract a 3D system.

With this picture it will easier to understand :

http://postimg.org/image/xmzoq3asp/

So I want to extract from the line that I found with the building a 3D system.

If you some answer.

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean when specific line? what makes them specific ?

Comment: line extracted from the building on the picture, corresponding to the real 3D Axis

Comment: Check the `solvePnP` function to go from 2D to 3D. You will need a real measurement from the scene in order to obtain a 3D system in real units.

Comment: I need to calibrate the camera to use solvePnP no ?

Comment: Yes, you need the calibration parameters.

Comment: Ok, I cannot do that, I don't want a calibration step right now, I will try to detect the floor (as a plane) and extract the normal from this plane. Any advice ?

Comment: Wont work you dont have enough parallel converging lines lines to make a good enough guess. If you had you could guess instead of solve.